# Display alert message javascript of files that are not being uploaded by html multiple upload form

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload, alert

I'm using html and php to upload multiple files. I want to have restriction of each files on max filesize and file types that user can upload. Everything works fine if user upload only one file, the javascript alert will prompt to tell whether it has exceed 8mb filesize or it is not pdf files. But the thing is, when user upload multiple files, the javascript won't be prompt as the page is being refreshed after user click upload button. Files that are exceed 8mb won't be uploaded, same as files that are not pdf files. But I hope the javascript will prompt out...

```
     $myFile = $_FILES['userfile'];
     $fileCount = count($myFile['name']);
     if ($fileCount > 2) {
        $error .= "Cannot upload more than ".$fileCount." files at once";
     }
     else {
        $errors = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
          if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] > 8388608) {
            $errors[] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
          }
          else {
             //upload each files
          }
        }
     if(count($errors) > 0) {
         //echo javascript alert dialog
        echo '<script>alert("Cannot upload more than 8Mb filesize");</script>';
        }
     }
```

Comment: can you show full code including html?

Comment: can you put here the code of your javascript?

Comment: I just edit my post :) Pls bear with me, quite not good in javascript..

Comment: I can't show the full code cos it is too long...